# need java script function which validate sql query and it should not allow dml like alter,update ,delete

Tags: javascript, regex

javascript regex validate sql query ex select * from emp.
it should return false if sql query string have DML like delete,update,drop,insert..

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following:

```
/^(?!delete|update|drop|insert).*/gi
```

JS Code:

```
/^(?!delete|update|drop|insert).*/gi.test(myString)
```